# LTR to RTL converter

Tags: html, css

I would like to convert (flip horizontally) my entire website to be used with RTL languages such as Hebrew and Arabic.

As far as I can imagine there are not a few properties I have to take care about in order to accomplish this task.

My website is pretty complicated in terms of CSS styling so I am looking for the most elegant and 100% working method to do so.

I have found some online tools but it seems they do not take care of every possible property and this simply breaks the website.

Can someone suggest a good and an elegant way?

Comment: Did you look at this?  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/

Comment: are you using sass or less, if so your task will be achieved very easily through some mixins

Comment: @jackblank, I do not want to change direction, I want to to flip it horizontaly, like a mirror effect.

Comment: @RajaSekar, could you please elaborate a little? As of right now I have plain CSS.

Comment: if you use plain css, then it will be pain to convert to rtl, so try to use sass or less. it will helps to do the rtl for you with less effort

Comment: @Dinly whenever I think of "mirror effect" I think of transform so I'm just going to say `html{ transform : scaleX(-1);}` If flips the page like a mirror vertically. probably not what you want but it flips and makes a mirror effect like what you mentioned in your last comment to me .

Answer (score 0):

- ***Using different stylesheets for the RTL version:***

This method became popular recently due to the rise of this plugins that automatically parse the CSS files and produce an RTL version.

1- [Automate RTL and LTR language directions supoort With Grunt and Sass](https://github.com/ahmadajmi/rtl-grunt-sass)

2- [Grunt plugin to convert CSS stylesheets between left-to-right and right-to-left](https://github.com/cssjanus/grunt-cssjanus)

3- [Bi App LESS](http://anasnakawa.github.io/bi-app-less/)

4- [Bi App SASS](http://anasnakawa.github.io/bi-app-sass/)

Also there is a Chrome extension called [My Style](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-style/ljdhjpmbnkbengahefamnhmegbdifhlb?hl=en) This extension add a `textarea` to the pages the user visit. It is toggled by pressing `ctrl + m`. Whenever CSS declaration is added to it, it will affect all the pages on the this domain. The CSS isn’t removed until the user remove it manually. Using this extension, I start adding the overrides till I get the prefect result.

---

note: this answer collected from many sources and I did not test them, i hope it helps in someway, *thanks !*